# CUDA: code that hangs works fine compiled with -g -G

Tags: cuda

I am having a CUDA code that hangs when executed on certain input data.

To debug it, I compiled it with -g -G, so that I can run it with cuda-gdb,
but when compiled with -g -G, the code works fine even outside of cuda-gdb.

How can I debug the code, and what could be the issue?

I have mutex mechanisms implemented at multiple places.

Comment: This is on a Tesla K20 GPU.

Comment: You should consider using CUDA atomics.

Comment: yes, that's what I am using.

Comment: The real answer is probably "don't write code with mutex mechanisms implemented at multiple place". The main difference between debug and non-debug builds is that shared memory in the kernel gets spilled to local memory so it can be inspected by the debugger. Do you use shared memory anywhere in your kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Try running with [cuda-memcheck](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-memcheck).

Comment: Do you mean decleared with __shared__? I do not use such memory anywhere.

Comment: I typed underscore, underscore, shared, underscore, underscore above.

Comment: I just ran the code with cuda-memcheck, after compiling with the additional parameters:
-G -Xcompiler -rdynamic

The code completes normally in cuda-memcheck, and does not hang.

What shall I do next to find the problem?

Comment: Perhaps there is a race condition in your mutex implementation.